# Could not connect to redis Instance at hostname:6379 in docker-compose

Tags: c#, redis, docker-compose, servicestack, connection-string

I am starting a dotnet core app and redis using docker-compose. Redis hostname is set to container name used in the docker network. The redis connection manager in service stack is setup using the connection string. However, it seems to always default back to localhost:6379

This has worked 2 weeks ago, same docker-compose.yaml, same code for redis client manager.

*Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90 - 
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01*

I have tried all sorts of connection string options as per servicestack.redis manual.

CODE:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new BasicRedisClientManager(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CACHE_CONNECTION_STRING")));
                container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());

Console.WriteLine($"Cache details: Cache={Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CACHE")}, CONNECTION_STRING={Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CACHE_CONNECTION_STRING")}");
```

LOGS:

```
Connection string used:
dev-backend        | Cache details: Cache=Redis, CONNECTION_STRING=dev-redis:6379

Error:
dev-backend        | fail: ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient[0]
dev-backend        |       Could not connect to redis Instance at localhost:6379
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What's the IP Address of dev-redis? i.e. `Dns.GetHostAddresses("dev-redis")[0];`

Comment: The IP address is defined in the docker-compose.yaml (10.5.0.4), which I have also tried as host in the RedisClientManager (both Pooled and Basic). Without success. Just wondering why the default host (localhsot:6379) is used?

Comment: It should only be using the address specified, the Error Message is [only echoing what's provided](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisNativeClient_Utils.cs#L229) so I'd be questioning where and what's really happening by looking at the full Exception StackTrace. If it can't connect by IP than it looks like you have a networking error as it can't make a TCP connection to your redis server which I would be looking to resolve first.